# How to use instance variables in rails ujs?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

This is what i used to do in **html.erb** earlier:

```
my markup
<script type="text/javascript">
    var somevalueFromInstance = "<%= @value_from_instance %>";
    // code directly using the someValueFromInstance
</script>
markup continues..
```

mostly i will place the **script** tag in a **content_for** block.

Now when i want to do this unobtrusive, i cannot have any **script** tags in the **html.erb**. The script lies in a javascript file. But how do i transport the **@value_from_instance** to the javascript file?

Is storing it in a **data**-attribute the only option to do this?

Also i want to do this on page load and not in an ajax request for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

The data-* attribute is do to that. It's the must simplest way to define your args or you can create some variable in a script tag in your HTML directly.

Comment: no limit in theory. You can put your array in content of script tag instead. Like do by javascript templating by example.

Comment: sorry.. i do not understand. can u please elaborate?

Comment: add your variable directly in your HTML and only variable. Without function.

Comment: yes and no. Yes because there are no code not reuse and No because there are some code. You can't be complete unobstrusive

Comment: well.. not convincing enough for my finicky client, who has a problem with script in markup :(